# Parse response of User Profile REST call in a workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to query the user profile service in a SharePoint 2013 workflow to retrive some properties. I am getting a valid response but unable to parse the json into workflow variables.

I am using httpsend to issue a GET call to url

```
http://<site>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)/UserProfileProperties?@v='Domain\UserName'
```

I am getting back a valid response, which looks like below

```
{
   "d":
   {
       "UserProfileProperties":
       {
           "results":
           [
..............
               ,{
                   "__metadata":
                   {
                       "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                   },
                   "Key": "AccountName",
                   "Value": "Domain\UserName",
                   "ValueType": "Edm.String"
               },
               {
                   "__metadata":
                   {
                       "type": "SP.KeyValue"
                   },
                   "Key": "FirstName",
                   "Value": "UsersFirstName",
                   "ValueType": "Edm.String"
               },
......
          ]
        }
   }
}
```

Now I am trying to extract values like firstname, manager properties. I used the `GetDynmaicValueProperties` and stored the value of `d/UserProfileProperties` into another dynamicvalue variable. I then tried to look on that variable to extract necessary information, but does not seem to be working.

When I loop on `d/UserProfileProperties/results`, I get each item as

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"FirstName","Value":"UserFirstName","ValueType":"Edm.String"}
```

How do I extract values from the json array structure (shown above).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? How do you loop trough results. Is it with foreach activity

Answer (score 1):

`GetDynmaicValueProperties in the`PropertyName` you should use

```
d/UserProfileProperties/results/(0)/Value
```

More on this topic http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/SP2013-Workflow-Dynamic-Values

Comment: Amal, that works when I know the index in the array. How do I extract value, when I do not know the index.

Comment: Use `d/UserProfileProperties` in Get item from a dictionary action [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7b1474b3-8ced-416a-a9b5-97e6ba05788e/getting-manager-name-from-spuserprofilespeoplemanager-rest-api-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Comment: I get an error that "Cannot implicity convert value of type dynamic value to dictionary". Also I am using visual studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the user profile properties and get the required property value.

The workflow stage should be as follows
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a 'get from dictionary' instead of just setting a variable equal to a literal.  This works on SharePoint Online.

[image: this works for me]